# Special Characters should not allow in first character in Reactive forms- Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

Here I have one small scenario where a user shouldn't be able to enter a special character as a starting character. Thereafter they should be allowed.

**component.ts**

```
this.new_org = this.fb.group({
    firstName: [this.data.name, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8),Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z \-\']+')]],
});
```

**component.html**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100%">
  <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
  <input class="add-org" matInput placeholder="" formControlName="firstName" type="text" required>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-error
  *ngIf="new_org.get('firstName').hasError('minlength') || new_org.get('firstName').hasError('pattern')">
  <span style="color:red;font-family:Open-Sans">Name must be 8 characters Long!.Special characters(@,#,!) and Numbers
    are not allowed.</span>
</mat-error>
```

How can I restrict special characters in the first entered character?

Comment: Why not use ``Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z '-]/)``? Did you finally solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

`Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z \-\']')` without plus in the regex should work

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom validator

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

export function ValidateString(control: FormControl) {
    let pattern = /[*\\/|":?><]/gi; // can change regex with your requirement
    //if validation fails, return error name & value of true
    if (pattern.test(control.value)) {
        return { validString: true };
    }
    //otherwise, if the validation passes, we simply return null
    return null;
}
```

And update your form

```
organisationName: [this.data.name, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8),ValidateString]],
```

Comment: Any easy way we can acheive this requriment

Comment: this way use can reuse validator in another control and form

Answer (score 0):

You already have a pattern validator so you can simply update the regex to something that suits your requirements. The current regex (`^[a-zA-Z \-\']+`) allows all regular letters and the following characters `\`, `-`, `'`, .

You can use a regex like this: `^\w.*` to make sure the first character is a regular character (a-zA-Z) and every other character can be anything.

Update:

Regex that doesn't allow numbers after first character, but anything else:
`^[a-zA-Z][^0-9]*$`

You can make the regex as big and complex as you please.

Comment: it should not allow numbers as well :)

Comment: @Rajesh I've updated the answer. You only need to find the right RegEx to fit your requirements. There's a lot of resources online that can help you find the perfect RegEx.